# Can't find the system library folder, Maven dependencies folder and other system folder in Project explrorer panel

Tags: maven, file, directory, project, project-properties

I've created a maven project and can start the project using tomcat server. But I can't see the necessary system folders to change or edit in the project explorer panel. I can see only the source folder Suppose I want to add mysql connector in maven dependencies but I can't find the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Simple. Open the project in Eclipse and go to `windows` >> `show views` click on `Project explorer` instead of `Navigator`

Then you will be able to see all the system files besides your main files.